# iPhoto: share across computers?

Tags: macos, file-sharing

How can I get all the editing, tagging etc features of iPhoto, but see the same thing on two OSX machines?

SIMPLE please!

Comment: It likely will not be possible to have two iPhoto instances running, working on the same data at the same time. And if it's possible, it'll likely result in data loss.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, as long as the versions of iPhoto are the same on both Macs, you should be able to copy /Users/username/Pictures/iPhoto Library from one machine to the other and it should have everything for you.  Of course, you'll need to keep these in sync between the machines.